# log4net not logging to event viewer from IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, log4net

I have a web service set up in my IIS, the appender that logs to a text file is working fine (the text file is in the same directory as where the web service is running from). The appender that writes to the Event Viewer isn't working, I'm currently connected to the web service as administrator so I should in theory be able to do this, what else should I check/see if I'm missing?

log4net.config:

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newlineExtra Info: %property{testProperty}%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO"/>
    <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
  </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
  <param name="ApplicationName" value="Lending Service" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message %newline %exception"  />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO"/>
    <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
  </filter> 
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

  <threshold value="DEBUG"/> 
  <file value="webLog.log"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
  </layout>

</appender>


<root>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
</root>

<logger name="LendingService.Global_asax">
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
</logger>

<logger name="LendingService.LendingService">
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />    
</logger>  

</log4net>
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What account is IIS running under?

Comment: The web application in IIS is running under administrator. Is that what you meant?

Comment: And the Application Pool? The app pool normally runs under its own account - ApplicationPoolIdentity (minimum privilege account).

Comment: In order to create the event source the log call needs to be made from an elevated process (eg elevated command window.)

Comment: We figured out a solution for it anyways, thanks!

Comment: @Ryguy did you post the solution? It would be helpful if not...

Answer (score 3):

The best way to find out what is going wrong is enable log4net interal debug, this will tell you where log4net is failing:

```
<configuration>
...
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>

...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

[Log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/faq.html)